# I'm trying to build pick random from each column system

Tags: python

For example, i would like this rows
Normal Numbers     |      Strong Number

1. ***1***  4   5   24  31  32       - 1
2. 9    16  ***17***    21  26  29   - 2
3. 17   ***19***    21  23  25  34   - 2
4. 3    13  21  ***24***    27  35.  - 5
5. 1    14  15  17  ***28***    37   - ***7***
6. 8    9   ***10***    18  29  32   - 3

you can see that i bolded the "Random numbers" for the example, to print a new row by each column: 1, 17, 19, 24, 28, 10 - 7
That from each row one column will be chosen randomly,  and then print all column been selected

now i have 4800+ rows i'm first trying to make them look like that JSON Design

```
{"1"    "4"     "5"     "24"    "31"    "32", - ,"1",}
{"9"    "16"    "17"    "21"    "26"    "29", - ,"2",}
{"17"   "19"    "21"    "23"    "25"    "34", - ,"2",}
{"3"    "13"    "21"    "24"    "27"    "35", - ,"5",}
{"1"    "14"    "15"    "17"    "28"    "37", - ,"7",}
{"8"    "9"     "10"    "18"    "29"    "32", - ,"3",}
```

instead of that

```
1 4 5 24 31 32 - 1
9 16 17 21 26 29 - 2
17 19 21 23 25 34 - 2
3 13 21 24 27 35. - 5
1 14 15 17 28 37 - 7
8 9 10 18 29 32 - 3
```

how can i pick from each row ONE column and print it combined to new row,
or change the indentation of my first chart to look like the JSON one.

Comment: do you keep it in some variable or in file? If you have it in file then first load it and convert to list of values.

Comment: BTW: json for `list` doesn'tf use `{ }` but `[ ]` - and it would need `"-"` instead of `-`. And you will have to write own code to format it.

Comment: if you keep it as numbers without `{ }`, `,` then you could read it as CSV file with space as separator - so it would be simpler to read and write it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it in file then it would be simpler if you would keep original indentation. You could use module `csv` to read it - using `space` as separator.

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and run it - but you should use `open()`

```
text = '''1 4 5 24 31 32 - 1
9 16 17 21 26 29 - 2
17 19 21 23 25 34 - 2
3 13 21 24 27 35 - 5
1 14 15 17 28 37 - 7
8 9 10 18 29 32 - 3'''

import io
import csv

#with open('data.txt') as fh:
with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=' ')
    data = list(csv_reader)
```

And now you can get number of rows and use `random` to select row and get value from row. If you will repeat it for different columns then you get expected values.

```
import random

nrows = len(data)     # number of rows
ncols = len(data[0])  # number of cols

values = []

for col in range(ncols):
    selected_row = random.randrange(0, nrows)
    selected_val = data[selected_row][col]

    print(col, selected_row, '->', selected_val)

    values.append(selected_val)
    
print(values)
```

Result:

```
['1', '9', '15', '24', '26', '32', '-', '2']
```

It gets even `-` so it will be easier to write it file.

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as fh:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter=' ')
    csv_writer.writerow(values)
```

---

Because some values repeates in different columns you may also use `while`-loop to skip repeated values

```
for col in range(ncols):
    while True:
        selected_row = random.randrange(0, nrows)
        selected_val = data[selected_row][col]
        if selected_val not in values:
            break
        print('skip:', selected_val)

    print(col, selected_row, '->', selected_val)
    values.append(selected_val)
```

---

Full code:

```
text = '''1 4 5 24 31 32 - 1
9 16 17 21 26 29 - 2
17 19 21 23 25 34 - 2
3 13 21 24 27 35 - 5
1 14 15 17 28 37 - 7
8 9 10 18 29 32 - 3'''

import io
import csv
import random

#with open('data.txt') as fh:
with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=' ')
    data = list(csv_reader)

nrows = len(data)
ncols = len(data[0])

values = []

for col in range(ncols):
    while True:
        selected_row = random.randrange(0, nrows)
        selected_val = data[selected_row][col]
        if selected_val not in values:
            break
        print('skip:', selected_val)

    print(col, selected_row, '->', selected_val)
    values.append(selected_val)
    
print(values)

with open('data.txt', 'a') as fh:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter=' ')
    csv_writer.writerow(values)
```